# How to remove words before and within tag using Python and BeautifulSoup?

Tags: python, gis, arcmap

Obviously, I am extremely new to Python and BS.

I am attempting to get information from a website using BeautifulSoup and this is the block that I want to extract data from:

```
        <div class="log-main">
        <div class="report">
        <div class="date">
            <p class="posted">Posted on  October&nbsp;22, 2018
            </p>   
        </div>


        <h1>Upper Bay Largemouth Bass Stocking</h1>
        <p class="subP">
            Type: <strong>Tidal</strong><br />
            Region: <strong>Central</strong><br />
            Location: <strong>Middle River</strong>
        </p>
```

The results that I want are the date without "Posted on" so October 22, 2018 and Type: Region: and Location: as a list but without the headers so only the text within the strong tags (Tidal, Central, and Middle River).

```
    October 22, 2018
    Tidal
    Central
    Middle River
```

Here's my code:

```
    import requests
    from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
    r = 
    requests.get('http://dnrweb.dnr.state.md.us/fisheries/fishingreport/log- 
    1.asp')
    soup = BeautifulSoup (r.text, 'html.parser')

    date = soup.find_all ('p', attrs={'class':'posted'})

    data = soup.find_all ('p', attrs={'class':'subP'})

    for strong_tag in data:
         print strong_tag.text

    for p_tag in date:
         print p_tag.text
```

And my results:

```
    Type: Tidal

            Region: Central

            Location: Middle River

    Posted on  October 22, 2018
```

The idea is that I want to eventually import this to an excel spreadsheet but I feel like I am close. Although I could be completely off. I've tried several things but it's difficult to find an exact answer through similar videos/threads. Thanks for any and all help I really appreciate it!

Comment: So you managed to get what you need but only not in the format you require?

Comment: I suppose so, I can't figure out how to exclude words either.